# Opportunity that has won coming back to Eloqua but not showing Contributing Campaigns in reports?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, eloqua, eloqua-bulk-api

I have done integration of Cx Sales and Eloqua using cx sale integration app sending the campaign member-like campaign contact and lead to Sales after that Lead is converted to Opportunity and set status as won it only shows in Sales campaign section image for reference
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxC6s.png)

when importing that Opportunity from the Sales to Eloqua using import in Opportunity Details section they not showing Contributing Campaigns for that opportunity like this image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXGsK.png)
due to this in Campaign Revenue Analysis in the cost opportunity won revenue is not showing an image for ref
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngg2N.png)

can anyone tell me what the problem

what I want if that opporunitiy is coming back from Sales to Eloqua then that opporunitiy should have the campaign name that opporunitiy has created with can any one tell me what is the problem